# Cannot enable iOS8 Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6, ios-app-extension

I'm trying to design a custom keyboard for iOS 8. Here are my development steps:

```
1. Created new project (Single view)
2. Created a new target: File > New > Target, and in the iOS template group chose the Custom Keyboard template.
```

Then I tried to enable the keyboard based on the documentation steps, which are:

```
1. Run the app
2. In iOS Simulator, press home button (Command+Shift+H)
3. Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Keyboards.
4. Tap Add New Keyboard.
5. In the Purchased Keyboards group, tap the name of your new keyboard. A modal view appears with a switch to enable your keyboard.
6. Tap the switch to enable your keyboard. A warning alert appears.
7. In the warning alert, tap Add Keyboard to finish enabling your new keyboard. Then tap Done.
```

My problem is in step 5. The modal view does not show a switch to activate the keyboard, it shows an empty view like bellow:

[image]

[image]

I clicked on Done button and it shows my Custom keyboard in activated list:

[image]

But when I want to use this keyboard, for example in spotlight, it won't show my keyboard

[image]

Comment: @SantaClaus Thanks for your comment, I have updated my question. Added two more pictures after I tap on Done button.

Comment: Looks like you have the language for that keyboard set as persian, and my guess would be that it is not appearing because your system language is not persian (or the text field you are typing in doesn't support persian).

Comment: You can also try just tapping on the button to change keyboard, rather than holding it like you were in the last screenshot.

Comment: @SantaClaus As you said it's a bug, I reset the simulator (iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...) and it shows my custom keyboard but with wrong title. I chose "AlakiKeyboard" and it shows "English" as a name. If you submit your first two comments as an answer, I'll mark it as an acceptable answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the done button will activate the keyboard. There are some definite bugs in those menus.

To change keyboards, you can also try just tapping on the button to change keyboard, rather than holding it like you were in the last screenshot.

Also, it looks like you have the language for that keyboard set as persian, and my guess would be that it is not appearing because your system language is not persian (or the text field you are typing in doesn't support persian).

I wouldn't be surprised if there are other bugs in the simulator that would affect this. I'm glad to hear you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

After you click done, it should install the keyboard, even if you don't see the list in the settings table.

About the keyboard not showing up - you need to kill the app before running a new keyboard. it's a known issue on the simulator.

good luck!